# UDP передача потокового видео

Tags: c#, сокет, tcp, udp

Почитал какой лучше протокол использовать для передачи потокового видео и везде говорится, что для этого лучше подходит UDP. Но при реализации возникли проблемы в виде ограничения 65к байт. А захватываемый кадр с камеры в среднем весит 100к+ байт и наверняка еще зависит от качества изображения камеры. Пробовал разрезать изображение на 2 части и отображать с 2 потоков, но сразу видно отставания. Как вообще передают видео поток по протоколу UDP? Или нужно использовать другой протокол?

Comment: Решается транскодингом видео.  Для моего случая лучше всего подошел rtmp

Comment: @АлексейГерусенко , Не поделитесь названием библиотек ?, которые вы использовали для rtmp.

Comment: Мы не на C# писали. Уверен, что разница не большая. Мы  с помощью ffmpeg гнали потоковое видео на сервер rtmp. Сервер rtmp этот поток фигачил в hls. Hls удобно тем что его можно поддержать везде без особых заморочек.